# Modify background color of a textarea (css) in grails

Tags: css, grails, textarea

I have a Grails application.
In a GSP page I add a textarea like this

```
<g:form controller="Comment" action="create" id="${post.id}">
    <textarea name="comment_text" placeholder="Add a comment ..." required></textarea><br />
    <button type="submit">Add the comment</button>
</g:form>
```

The problem is my textarea is red by default when it is empty (it is "classic" when I begin to fill it). I have tried to modify the css property with

```
textarea {
    background-color: white;
}
```

but it does nothing. I don't know how to have a "classic" texarea with a white background.

Comment: try giving `background-color: white !important;`

Comment: It looks as if because it is required a class is added to turn it red.  If you inspect the element (right click on textarea and select inspect element in ff or chrome) you will see what class is being added to it to make it red.  You can then override / change this in your stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the default Grails CSS files make it red because it is `required`. Try removing this attribute.